# Retrieving Previous Fiscal Month's Dates in VBA Module

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

My current module below successfully retrieves the dates for the current FiscalMonth from my tbl_calendar. How do I need to alter this code to where the dates retrieved are for the previous fiscal month?

```
 Function getDates(Optional forDate As String = "1/31/1999") As String 
  Dim rst As Recordset
  getDateRange = vbNullString


If forDate = "1/31/1999" Then

   forDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
End If

If DatePart("d", DateAdd("d", 1, forDate)) = 1 Then
  eom = True
End If

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Day, FiscalMonth, FiscalYear 
from tbl_Calendar where FiscalYear = (SELECT FIscalYear from tbl_Calendar 
where day = #" & _
Format(forDate, "Short Date") & "#) and FiscalMonth = (SELECT FiscalMonth 
from tbl_Calendar where day = #" & _
Format(forDate, "Short Date") & "#)")


If rst.EOF Then Exit Function
 rst.MoveLast
 rst.MoveFirst
 getDates = CStr(rst.Fields("day").Value) & ";"
 rst.MoveLast
If DateDiff("d", rst.Fields("day").Value, forDate) < 0 Then
    eom = "False"
Else
    eom = rst.Fields("FiscalMonth").Value & ", " & 
rst.Fields("FiscalYear").Value
 End If
getDates = getDates & IIf(DateDiff("d", rst.Fields("day").Value, forDate) 
< 0, CStr(forDate), CStr(rst.Fields("day").Value)) & ";" & eom
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Might be an idea to post the SQL table structures and ask the SQL guys. What the hell is a TBL_whatever ? :) Can be anything. No Structure = no SQL string to help.

Comment: It seems that it depends on the date that you pass to it as a parameter.

Comment: First problem is taking a date parameter `As String`. Treat `Date` values as dates, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [DateSerial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dateserial-function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) to build a fiscal date, then subtract one month. Additionally, consider re-writing query for a [self join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) to avoid subqueries. Also, use parameterization with [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao). to run SQL in VBA for readability and maintainability without concatenation or punctuation with `#` enclosures:

**SQL**

Current Query

```sql
SELECT [Day], FiscalMonth, FiscalYear 
FROM tbl_Calendar 
WHERE FiscalYear = (SELECT FiscalYear FROM tbl_Calendar WHERE [Day] = #10/24/2019#)
  AND FiscalMonth = (SELECT FiscalMonth FROM tbl_Calendar WHERE [Day] = #10/24/2019#)
```

Adjusted Original Query *(remove subqueries that point to same source)*

```sql
SELECT c.[Day], c.FiscalMonth, c.FiscalYear 
FROM tbl_Calendar c
INNER JOIN tbl_Calendar c2
  ON c.FiscalYear = c2.FiscalYear 
  AND c.FiscalMonth = c2.FiscalMonth
WHERE c2.[Day] = #10/24/2019#
```

Adjusted Last Fiscal Month Query *(better as a saved query for optimization)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [DateParam] AS Datetime;
SELECT c.[Day], c.FiscalMonth, c.FiscalYear 
FROM tbl_Calendar c
INNER JOIN tbl_Calendar c2
  ON DATESERIAL(c.FiscalYear, c.FiscalMonth, 1) = 
     DATEADD('m', -1, DATESERIAL(c2.FiscalYear, c2.FiscalMonth, 1))
WHERE c2.[Day] = [DateParam]
```

**VBA**

```vb
Function getDates(Optional forDate As Date = #1/31/1999#) As String 
     Dim qdf As QueryDef, rst As Recordset
     Dim sql As String
     getDateRange = vbNullString

     ' SQL (NO DATA)
     sql = "PARAMETERS [DateParam] AS Datetime;" _
            & " SELECT c.[Day], c.FiscalMonth, c.FiscalYear" _
            & " FROM tbl_Calendar c" _
            & " INNER JOIN tbl_Calendar c2" _
            & "    ON DATESERIAL(c.FiscalYear, c.FiscalMonth, 1) =" _
            & "       DATEADD('m', -1, DATESERIAL(c2.FiscalYear, c.FiscalMonth, 1))" _
            & " WHERE c2.[Day] = [DateParam]" _

     If forDate = DateValue("1/31/1999") Then
          forDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
     End If

     If DatePart("d", DateAdd("d", 1, forDate)) = 1 Then
          eom = True
     End If

     ' CREATE TEMP QUERYDEF AND BIND PARAM
     Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", sql)  ' OR  .CreateQueryDef("mySavedQuery") 
     qdf![DateParam] = forDate   

     ' OPEN RECORDSET
     Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()
     '... same code as before ...  

     rst.Close: qdf.Close    
     Set rst = Nothing: Set qdf = Nothing
End Function
```